# The noun form of "well-defined"

Tags: nouns, writing

What’s the noun of *well-defined* (meaning that something is defined well in a mathematical sense). Also, could you show me more examples of the same structure/principle (of transforming the adjective form to noun)?

I guess it is *well-definedness*, but Google tells me that no one uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noun is ***well-definedness***, as you would expect.

I do not know what Google tells you, it gives me some 30k hits on this collocation. For example, in the [Wikipedia article on well-defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined):

> ... Or, in other words: A definition always claims its own well-definedness.

This particular case of conversion may be a bit counterintuitive because the *well-* should really modify an adjective rather than a noun. (Cf. [*well-order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order)). On the other hand, it's only well that the noun refers *unambiguously* to its adjective; that's what a mathematician will appreciate.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add quote in `"well-definedness".`

Answer (score 2):

You could try ***precision***, or ***exactness***, both of which most dictionaries will recognise. *Succinctness* is a word, though it has a slightly different meaning, more *well-expressed* than *well-defined*.

It is worth remembering that in language there is often no precise, exact, or well-defined answer to a question like this. But there is often a succinct one.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined):

> In mathematics, an expression is called well-defined or **unambiguous** if its definition assigns it a unique interpretation or value.

My emphasis added.

So if I've read your question correctly, unambiguity seems like the closest fit:

> Noun   1.  unambiguity - clarity achieved by the avoidance of ambiguity

Source: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unambiguity).