# Word for an exhaustive description of something

Tags: nouns, terminology

A "description" of something does not necessarily have to *completely* describe the thing. For example, one could describe a mouse as "small and grey", but this leaves out a lot of information. Someone who did not know what a mouse was would have a very incomplete picture.

Is there a word for a description which aims to capture something as completely as possible, by reducing it to its components?

I have a feeling there is a word for this which maybe ends in -onomy or -ology.

I don't think it's taxonomy because that refers to an overarching system of description/classification covering many different "things".

Comment: @NVZ I am curious.  Why do you put this as a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @thomj1332 feel free to use my comments into an answer of your own. :)

Comment: Perhaps **morphology** or **physiology**?

Comment: It is a *complete description* or a *complete specification*.

Comment: The non-count noun 'well-definedness' is given at [The noun form of "well-defined"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326204/the-noun-form-of-well-defined). I wouldn't use 'well-definition' though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider (full) *specification*.

> **specification** *noun*
>   1 An act of identifying something precisely or of stating a precise requirement.
>   ‘give a full specification of the job advertised’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/specification)

For a more clinical analysis of the item, consider *breakdown*:

> **breakdown** *noun*
>   3.1 An explanatory analysis, especially of statistics.
>   ‘Under another new directive, all products containing any allergens must include details of their chemical breakdown.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/breakdown)

For a more analogical term taken from the field of design, consider *blueprint* ([definition 1.1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blueprint)).

Moving somewhat further afield, you might want to consider [*gene*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gene) as the specification for a living thing.

Comment: I like this but it has the implication of being _prior_ to the existence of the thing specified. **Analysis** is similar but sounds like it comes _after_. I can't seem to think of something more neutral.

Comment: @SteveLovell A *breakdown*, perhaps? I've added it to my answer.

Comment: It's interesting that ODO gives ' ... identifying something precisely' but then seems to feel the need to add 'full'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, umm, *precisely*. ODO sources their examples [from their corpora](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/01/dictionary-examples/). Admittedly, the examples retained were chosen by their editorial team.

Answer (score -2):

***taxonomy*** ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/taxonomy)) (per NVZ's comment)

> from *Biology*: the science dealing with the description, identification,
>   naming, and classification of organisms.

Comment: that may be the word i was thinking of, but if so the meaning is not quite what i had in mind. thanks though !

Comment: Taxonomy is about classification, not describing. Even the complete Dictionary.com definition (not given here) expresses this.